# Movie Player in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, video, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I want to download an mp4 file, an iPhone movie player (MPMoviePlayerController) pops out and plays the video. My question is: can I get some kind of a message that it pops up or perhaps even prevent it from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is setting a delegate for your UIWebView and implementing `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. Return NO if it's an mp4 (or mov) file.

Comment: Yeah I tought about that, but how do you know if it's an mp4 file? By parsing the url? This is not accurate.